# How to remove stroke line around UIImageView with rounded corners and thick border

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, ios9

I have create circle UIImageView with rounded corners and thick border:

```
var img1: UIImageView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()
  img1.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
  img1.layer.borderWidth = 3
  img1.layer.cornerRadius = 22
  img1.layer.masksToBounds = true
}
```

But I get the following ugly image with thine stroke line around it:
[Circle image with stroke](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EbaaS.png)

I'm using border width here to make spacing between multiple images, like here: [Multiple images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UHyhx.png)

Comment: can you try border width 0

Comment: I do really need border width to make spacing between images.

Comment: Have you tried `img1.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor` and `img1.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()`?

Comment: so what u actually wants...?

Comment: As seen your second image I think its not because of border its because not proper spacing between ImageViews,is it being created programmatically or using storyboard?

Comment: @RamaniAshish I want create several overlapping circular images add circular spacing between them like in the second link.

Comment: @AkshayHastekar it was created in storyboard. But with only one image the same problem remains.